# Thread skip Database DataSnapshot (FireBase)

Tags: swift, database, multithreading, firebase, uitableview

I'm trying to append to my array "Posts" from database but It looks like that The main Thread skip my instructions and jump right to numberOfRowsInSection and crash because array is nil!

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

any Ideas how to force the Thread to execute first my append to array instructions ?

Here is the code:

```
var pods: [Pod]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadPosts()
}

func loadPosts() {
   Database.database().reference().child("Posts").observe(.childAdded) { (DataSnapshot) in
        if let dict = DataSnapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let title = dict["title"] as! String
            let description = dict["description"] as! String
            let imageURL = dict["image"] as! String
            let pod = Pod(image: imageURL, title: title, description: description)
            self.pods.append(pod)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return pods.count
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current data source array will be always `nil` since you never assign it.

So instead, create your data source array as empty array of `Pod` objects

```
var pods = [Pod]()
```